# How to achieve to get Gatsby 5 (JS-React-framework) to work together with Gatsby-plugins for version 4?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, gatsby

I tried to install Gatsby-themes (a special kind of Gatsby-plugins) into my Gatsby-project.
While there are some themes available, all except one give error-messages like this one:

> ```
> npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
> npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! While resolving: gatsby-documentation@1.0.0
> npm ERR! Found: gatsby@5.12.11
> npm ERR! node_modules/gatsby
> npm ERR!   gatsby@"^5.11.0" from the root project
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
> npm ERR! peer gatsby@"^4.0.0" from gatsby-theme-blog@4.0.0
> npm ERR! node_modules/gatsby-theme-blog
> npm ERR!   gatsby-theme-blog@"*" from the root project
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
> npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
> npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR!
> ```

The problem I see here, is that the theme/plugin obviously needs Gatsby version 4 while I work with version 5.
This would not be that bad, but the problem is: all, except one, available Gatsby-themes cannot be installed because of this or a similar reason.
Does this mean, I have to wait until some of the themes are migrated to version 5?
While this seems reasonable, I have the feeling that I miss something here. Mainly because Gatsby  version 5 is out for some time now and I cannot imagine that nearly all themes break the dependency to the main Gatsby version AND don't fix this.

Any ideas?

What I tried and what I was expecting:

I tried out all Gatsby-themes I could find. I expected that some, because Gatsby version 5 is not that new, would work. It turned out that only one theme could be installed, but that one, installed via

> npm install gatsby-theme-ui-preset

can only be used with TypeScript instead of JavaScript. I want to avoid TypeScript because this would introduce an unnecessary additional element into the technology-stack.

Comment: Welcome. Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. We're not a discussion forum and your question is rather broad. You're generally expected to show some code and ask about it.

Comment: Yes, you generally have to wait for theme and plugin developers to migrate to new versions of software. That's the way it works.

Comment: @isherwood: I know that it works this way generally. The problem here: it doesn't seem to work this way here. And: I don't want to start a discussion. I think I am missing something here. Or maybe there is a simple solution for this.